# Is Waterdeep faction membership mutually exclusive?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, waterdeep-dragon-heist, factions

*Waterdeep: Dragon Heist* has multiple factions which PCs can belong to, or join. These include Lord's Alliance, Emerald Enclave, Bregan D'aerthe, etc. If a PC matches the requisites for more than one of these factions, can he join multiple ones?

For example, could a drow druid join both Emerald Enclave and Bregan D'aerthe? Or is membership exclusive, and PCs have to pick a single faction to work with?

Yesterday, I told my players that they could belong to multiple factions as long as their missions and actions didn't cross each other. But it was a DM's call in the moment, and I wanted to confirm my ruling.

Comment: *strongly* related, but it's been long enough since I read the W:DH new faction material that I'm loath to mark as a dupe: [can one join multiple factions in 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89918/23970)